# Best way to transform Jupyter notebook code in a web app

Tags: python-3.x, jupyter-notebook

Suppose, I have a Jupyter notebook that contains the code of Image Captioning. Let's say [this](https://colab.research.google.com/github/tensorflow/docs/blob/master/site/en/tutorials/text/image_captioning.ipynb) is our example notebook. This is a simple machine learning model where the workflow is like loading the data, training the model, and using the model to predict the caption for any image.

What I want to learn is how to make a simple publicly available web app (like [this](https://www.timelefttolive.com/)) where the users can just upload their image or provide a link to their image and get the required captions as output.

Answer (score 1):

You can try to use [Mercury](https://github.com/mljar/mercury). It tranforms Jupyter notebooks into web app by adding YAML header in the first raw cell in the notebook. You can easily define an image upload as input. Example YAML config:

```yaml
title: App title
description: App description
params:
    my_image:
        input: file
        label: Please upload image
        maxFileSize: 1MB
```

In the next cell you need to define variable with file name

```py
my_image = "my_image.png"
```

In the rest cells you should have your notebooks cells.